# Drawing verticle charts in PHP

Tags: php, charts, diagram

Forgive me as this is my first ever stack overflow post.

I am trying to draw vertical lines that represent the over head flight path of a Frisbee. I've looked at google charts, canvasjs, and a few PHP libraries but none yielding the results I am looking for because they almost are all linear graphs going from left to right and the type of lines/graph I am looking for (and dont know how to describe) See Link. [Crude drawing of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5GPl.png)

I'm open to learning other languages or libraries that would help with this so I guess what I am looking for is if anyone knows about one that I have not found yet!

Thank you, and again if this is bad formatting as this is my first attempt at posting on this site!

Comment: Raw svg or [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#shapes-d3-shape)?

Comment: I havent heard of those but will give them a look! Thank you

Comment: I see now your asking which type of chart. I suppose either would work. I looked at d3 and seems like that would be preferred. Its mostly just a web app I want to send to some of my friends

Comment: Since you said no graph libraries fitted, I suggested d3. You may find a graph type that fits your case in d3, but it's not a "chart library" (c3 would be better suited). It has drawing primitives (backed by [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)), axis, etc. It's more of a toolkit.

Comment: thank you I will check it out!